# adding attribute to an existing node

Tags: pdf-generation, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, jaxp

i need to add an attribute initial-page-number to a tag fo:sequence

tha tag is

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="alternating" initial-page-number="1"><fo:page-sequence>
..
...
</fo:page-sequence>
```

become

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="alternating" initial-page-number="1">
..
</fo:page-sequence>
```

but with the xslt i obtain two fo:page:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="alternating" initial-page-number="1"><fo:page-sequence>
</fo:page-sequence></fo:page-sequence>
```

How can i replace old fo:page-sequence with new one?

This is my xsl stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:template match="ss:split/fo:page-sequence">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@master-reference['alternating']">
    <xsl:element name="fo:page-sequence">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:attribute name="initial-page-number">
            <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match='comment()'>
 <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@*|*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet creates an `fo:page-sequence` using `<xsl:element name="fo:page-sequence">`, and another one with `<xsl:copy>` (as the matching element is an `fo:page-sequence`).

Just remove the `xsl:copy` (but leave `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>`, as you want to process the children of the current node!) and you should get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet changes every `fo:page-sequence` because the predicate `['alternating']` is always true.

You can check for the `master-reference` value in the match pattern, plus you can just copy the existing attributes, and you can copy the contents of the `fo:page-sequence` since it won't contain another `fo:page-sequence`:

```
<xsl:template
      match="ss:split/fo:page-sequence[@master-reference = 'alternating']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="initial-page-number">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```